# Term for every individual / company in contact with me

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I am creating a application which collects every person that i have been in contact with or have worked with. So if i had an interaction with some one or some company, i want to collect details about that person / company.But the term that i am looking for describes everyone collectively that maybe a bank, a friend, a company, a customer , etc ... . I was wondering what is the actual term for calling them collectively ?

Is it Persona ? Entity ? Person ?

Comment: If there were such a term it would be "contact" but there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to wikipedia :
A legal entity is a legal construct through which the law allows a group of natural persons to act as if they were a single person for certain purposes. The most common purposes are lawsuits, property ownership, and contracts.

So every company is a legal entity which can act as a single person. So the word i should use is Person.